# how to access controller scope from a 2 level directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to build generic code as much as possible.

So I'm having 2 directives, one nested inside the other while I want the nested directive to call a method on the main controller $scope.

But instead it requests the method on the parent directive, I want to know how to execute a method against the main controller scope instead of the parent directive.

Here is a sample code for my issue
My HTML should look something like this:

```
<div ng-controller='mainctrl'>
  <div validator>
    <div datepicker select-event='datepickerSelected()'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

var mainctrl = function($scope){
  $scope.datepickerSelected = function(){
    //I WANT TO ACCESS THIS METHOD
  }
}

app.directive("validator",function(){
  return {
    scope : {
      //the datepicker directive requests a datepickerSelected() method on this scope
      //while I want it to access the mainctrl scope
    }
    link: function(scope){
      //some code
    }
  }
});

app.directive("datepicker", function(){
  return{
    scope: {
      selectEvent: '&'
    }
    link: function(scope, elem){
      //example code
      $(elem).click(scope.selectEvent); //want this to access mainctrl instead validator directive
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the validator directive's scope property, thus eliminating its isolated scope. That means that validator will have the same scope that it is nested in (your controller) and datepicker will use that scope.

Another option if you want both to have isolated scopes (doesn't sound like you do) is to pass  the function through to "validator's" scope.

Comment: Actually i do really want 2 isolated scopes, but I cant use the 2nd option because I would really lose the 'generic' touch o_0
it's is important to note that the 'validator' directive is actually quite big one which would be used quite often that is why I need a scope of it own for him, to make him as generic as possible as well

Comment: Hmm. I'd be interested if there were another solution. The thing is, it sounds like the nature of directive 1 to setup directive 2, so it seems to need to know about that function. As I understand it, it would be just like having 1 massive function that you break down into 3 - the first function may know about things (parameters) that the last one doesn't, but it probably needs to pass some of those params to the 2nd function which then passes them to the 3rd function. In that scenario, it doesn't mean the functions aren't generic. Not sure if your case is the same, but it seems like it to me.